# Modify generic reference inside class

Tags: c++, generics, boost

I have to admit the title sounds a little strange. But i will demonstrate you what i want to have in C++:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  template<typename T>
  void set( T& val ) {
    _value = val;
  }

  void someOtherFunction() {
    _value = std::string("12") //this is always a std::string
  }

private:
  boost::any _value;
};

int main() {
  MyClass a;
  int val;
  a.set(val);
  a.someOtherFunction();

  std::cout << val << std::endl;

}
```

So i expect val inside main to become 12. This also should work for any (castable) type i set with MyClass.set().
Is there any chance to achieve that?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a `std::string` is not castable to an `int` (or much else for that matter), I assume you want to parse the string. `boost::any` also stores by value rather than by reference, so you'll probably have to implement your own container, something like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct value_holder
{
  virtual ~value_holder() {}
  virtual void operator=(const std::string& source) = 0;
};

template<typename T> struct value_holder_impl: value_holder
{
  T& value;

  value_holder_impl(T& v): value(v) {}

  void operator=(const std::string& source) {
    std::istringstream(source) >> value;
  }
};

class MyClass {
public:
  template<typename T>
  void set( T& val ) {
    _value = std::make_shared<value_holder_impl<T>>(val);
  }

  void someOtherFunction() {
    *_value = std::string("12");
  }

private:
  std::shared_ptr<value_holder> _value;
};

int main() {
  MyClass a;
  int val;
  a.set(val);
  a.someOtherFunction();

  std::cout << val << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Only the streaming operator (istringstream) does not work for some reason. But i have to use boost::lexical_cast anyway because of some specific type casts.